# How many tries to roll a 6?

Tags: mathematics, probability, dice, paradox

Suppose you roll a (fair, 6-sided, perfectly ordinary) die repeatedly until you roll a 6. As is well known, the expected (i.e., long-term average over many trials) number of rolls required is 6.

Now suppose we ask this question *conditional on never having rolled any odd numbers*. That is, suppose you learn that someone has followed the procedure above, and that they rolled only even numbers up to the point where they rolled that 6. **What is the expected number of rolls they took?**

(That is: What is the expected number of rolls taken to roll a 6, conditional on having got no odd numbers *in the process of rolling that 6*? The question is *not* anything like "what's the expected number of rolls next time, given that you didn't get any odd numbers last time?". I've added this paragraph and slightly reworded the question above because it seems from comments that some readers interpreted the question in an unintended way.)

---

This question is interesting because there is an *extremely tempting* wrong answer.

Some history: The question seems to have first been asked by Elchanan Mossel while teaching an undergraduate probability course at the University of Pennsylvania in 2014-15. Gil Kalai posted it on his blog as part of his [Test Your Intuition](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2017/09/07/tyi-30-expected-number-of-dice-throws/) series, and then posted a [followup](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2017/09/08/elchanan-mossels-amazing-dice-paradox-answers-to-tyi-30/). There is interesting discussion in the comments of both. And here is a [nice little article](http://www.yichijin.com/files/elchanan.pdf) about the question, in PDF form.

WARNING: All the links in the paragraph above may take you to places that give away some or all of the solution. If you want to solve the puzzle for yourself, don't follow those links until you've done it.

---

[See [this Meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6149/should-elchanan-mossels-dice-puzzle-be-undeleted) for some relevant PSE-specific context, which in particular explains why this is community wiki. An older question has been merged into this one, and it's possible that some details of answers or comments may look odd as a result.]

Comment: I don't see what's so interesting about it; it looks like a basic probability textbook exercise.

Comment: This is a poorly formulated puzzle. The problem is that we are first given a random number generator with **specific properties**. The formulation strongly implies that we have a **fair six-sided die**. We know the properties of such a die: when rolled it will give a result of 1 to 6, each with an equal 1/6 probability, and the result is independent of previous results. But then you go on to say that when rolling this particular die, the distribution of results will **not** be that, and you are not specific **why** the die will have a non-standard result distribution. (continued)

Comment: In other words: we cannot be sure what the distribution function of this die actually is. Why are we getting only evens? Is the die **unfair** so that it only rolls evens? Is someone **excluding results** when odds are rolled? Do we **reset the throw count** when odds are rolled? Is there **any other reason** for the non-uniform result distribution? So it is a poorly formulated puzzle, and I hold the opinion that we do not have the information we need to answer it.

Comment: I suspect this question is written wrong, since as @MichaelKarnerfors points out it's trivial as written.   How about,  "of all rolls which returned only even numbers, what's the expected number of rolls to get a 6?".  Then it's similar to an old Marylin vos Savant question about the odds of two Aces in a Bridge hand when the owner announces either "I have an Ace" vs.  "I have the Ace of Spades"

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors The problem is completely unambiguous as long as you are familiar with conditional probability. If X is a random variable and A is an event, then the expected value of X conditioned on A is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nP(X=n\cap A)/P(A)$. Here, X is the number of rolls and A is the event that all rolls are even. This is equivalent to both your "exclude roll counts" and "reset throw count" interpretations.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Hm... I am still not certain. Does what you wrote that take into account that we **stop** throwing the die once the 6 has been reached?

Comment: Yes. To define the event A and random variable X, you must first define the sample space, S, that they live in. Define S to be the set of all finite sequences of die rolls where the last roll is 6 and no previous rolls are 6. Then A is the subset of such sequences which are all even, and X is the function which returns the length of a sequence. This is how the stopping condition is taken into account. @MichaelKarnerfors

Comment: @MikeEarnest I am still doubtful but what you say makes sense. It just does not click intuitively with me at this point. If you have time I would appreciate if you could tell me where I am going wrong in my answer.

Comment: Why does the recursion $n=1/3+2/3*(n+1)$ not hold true? I do not understand...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - the puzzle is fundamentally, technically flawed. It makes no sense. It should be closed.

Comment: @Myridium The question is not "What is the probability of rolling a 6", so there is something more to it. It is my opinion that the puzzle makes perfectly good sense; of course I could be wrong (though if I am then I, and multiple other professional mathematicians, have made a serious error) but you haven't really made any argument for that.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors, if you're reading this, would you like me to undelete the answer you wrote on the earlier version of this question?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - shall I repeat everything that Michael has said? The question states that it's a fair die. In which case all the properties, such as the expected number of rolls before landing a 6, are that of a fair die. If the die landed on odd numbers 100 times, **and it was a fair die**, then it was just a stroke of luck. The expected number of rolls to get any given number is 6.

Comment: @Myridium Nope, no need to repeat what Michael said if it exactly matches what you want to say. Michael objects that "you go on to say that when rolling this particular die, the distribution of results will not be that" but the question *does not say that*. It doesn't in any way claim that something special happens when the die is rolled; it asks about probabilities *conditional on that something special happening to happen*.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - The question, by its mere existence, implies that somehow the probability distribution, and independence of rolls, becomes alterred from that of a fair die after someone has rolled it a few times and gotten even numbers. As Michael has said, we have no way of knowing how that probability distribution was alterred. All bets are off, because the author contradicts themselves in the premises of the puzzle. First they say it's a fair die, then they refute the correct answer based on that premise (6 expected rolls for a fair die; OP accepted answer of 3/2).

Comment: The question does not imply any such thing. That isn't how conditional probability works. It may -- or may not -- be instructive to consider the following question. A fair die is rolled until it comes up 6. *Conditional on its having come up 6 on the first roll*, how many rolls did it take? Of course the answer to this question is 1, even though it's a fair die and only comes up 6 one-sixth of the time. And yes, coming up 6 on the first roll would be "just a stroke of luck". This is a question about probability, after all.

Comment: Perhaps my objection is limited to this statement: *...you learn that someone has followed the procedure above, and that they rolled only even numbers up to the point where they rolled that 6. What is the expected number of rolls then?*. Perhaps what the author meant to ask was the expected number of rolls that **this someone did before reaching their roll of 6 in this particular streak of even numbers**?

Comment: That is exactly what the question is intended to mean, yes.

Comment: I've reworded very slightly and added a paragraph of attempted clarification. Any better now?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The answer is indeed...

> 1<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> rolls

...because the question is equivalent to...

> What is 1 more than the average number of
>  consecutive rolls of only **2**s and/or **4**s
>  before *any* other roll terminates the series?
>  
>  One way to see this equivalence is to note that
>  only **2**/**4** streaks terminated by **6** are considered.
>  (A first-roll **6** terminates
>   a **2**/**4** streak of length 0.)
>  Yet the average length of those streaks is the same as of streaks
>  terminated by **1**, **3** or **5**.
>  Collect all such streaks, including those terminated by **6**,
>  and the result is all streaks of **2**/**4**,
>  each with the same expected length.

Calculations:

> E = expected number of consecutive even rolls
>      up to and including the first **6**
>  
>     
>    = (expected number of consecutive **2**s and/or **4**s)
>      + (one more roll of **6**)
>  
>     
>    = T + 1
>  
> where
>     
>  T = expected number of consecutive **2**s and/or **4**s
>      before some other roll
>  
>     
>    = (probability of **2** or **4**)
>        ×  
>      (1 for this roll + expected subsequent **2**s and/or **4**s)
>  
>     
>    = <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub> (1 + T)
>  
>    so
>     
>  T = <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>
>  
>    thus
>     
>  E = T + 1
>  
>     
>    = 1<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>

Comment: Note to possibly add in a future edit: 

The expected number of rolls is surprisingly small,
but that is because most often it will include
just 1 roll, a lone **6**,
as odd numbers are more likely than non-**6** even numbers to precede any **6**.

Comment: Why is the probability of a 2 or 4 only 1/3? Surely if you have been told that all throws were not odd that leave the chance of it being a 2 or 4 as 2/3?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out something that
should/will be added to the answer, @Chris, when I figure out a clearer explanation than this, for now:
The 1/3 probability for **2** or **4** is in the context of all rolls,
where the sequences are generated and every roll has an equal 1/6 chance.
The all-even sequences in question do not have
equal 1/3 probabilities for **2** and for **6**, for instance,
as any number of **2**s may occur but only one **6**.

Comment: I think the problem I'm having may be that as michael says in comments the question isn't well specified. My reading is that it says that a given condition is that all rolls are even. So the probability of getting a 1, 3 or 5 is 0. We are told that they are never rolled. This is why I am confused as to how for any given roll of the dice the probability of the result being 2 or 4 is not 2/3. I am having trouble reading the question in such a way as conforms with the answers here (though lots of people seem to agree with your reading).

Comment: I notice that Michael has actually added an answer now which agrees with the answer that I got.

Comment: Perhaps the puzzle statement will be revised to be more clear, @Chris,
but the trap is to think that "all-even sequences ending in **6**"
includes all "sequences that have only even rolls" rather than just
"sequences with only **2s/4**s before a final **6**."
I still want to figure out a clearer explanation,
but it's important that the sequences in question were generated
when each **6** had a 1/6 chance and 
when each **2s/4**s sequence had a 3/4 chance of being discarded.
That 3/4 chance is a goodie, too,
as there are 4 possible rolls that terminate a **2s/4**s sequence.

Comment: Ah... So I think in my interpretation rolls of 1,3,5 are strictly forbidden to occur whereas in your interpretation they may occur but cause the sequence to be discarded and discounted from the results?

Comment: I think this pretty much goes to show that the problem here is that the question is just badly specified. :(

Comment: Sigh, @Chris, all too often the primary puzzle is to figure out what is the actual intended puzzle. Many solutions, too, only make sense to the solver and the puzzle's poser, until comments help point out how much was incorrectly assumed to have been clear. I'm looking forward to adding "discussion" to this solution thanks to your comments.

Comment: As Mike mentioned on the comments to the main question, @Chris, this is not at all ambiguous if you're familiar with conditional probability, but what it basically means is - someone rolled a fair die until they rolled a 6. If I give you the extra information that only evens were rolled, how does this change your expectation of the number of throws? (this does not change the fairness of the die, or the rolling procedure. it's just extra information about how this particular roll went)

Comment: A great answer, with a simple and clean argument.

Comment: @ffao: That is a much better phrasing of it - I think I understand where you are coming from now! :)

Answer (score 40):

This surprisingly beguiling puzzle may also be solved
with a surprisingly unsophisticated approach.
Symmetry, by itself, predicts the average length of
evens-only sequences ending with **6** to be...

> ...1 <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>  throws.

Start with *T*  many random throws:
                 `2153664315121226553111444142566363625461525 . . 3644464461`

Sift them into 4 groups that,
due to symmetric criteria, are each expected
to include <sup>*T*</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub>  throws.

Every **1** and any preceding **2**s/**4**s:  
                 `21......1.121......1114441.............1... . . .........1`


Every **3** and any preceding **2**s/**4**s:  
                 `...3..43..........3............3.3......... . . 3.........`


Every **5** and any preceding **2**s/**4**s:  
                 `..5......5......55........425......25...525 . . ..........`


Every **6** and any preceding **2**s/**4**s:  
                 `....66.......226.............66.6.6..46.... . . .64446446.`

The last group, of **6**s and their preceding **2**s/**4**s,
precisely contains every evens-ending-with-**6**
sequence considered by the puzzle.
 
The number of such sequences is just the original number of **6**s,
as every **6** is in exactly one such sequence.
 
From **6**’s symmetry with the other 5 equally-likely
throws —**1**, **2**,
                     **3**, **4** and **5** — that
number is expected to be
<sup>*T*</sup> ⁄<sub>6</sub>  sequences.

Thus...

> (Average length)   =  
>      (number of throws in these sequences)
>        /  
>      (number of sequences)
>  
>          =  
>      <sup>*T*</sup> ⁄<sub>4</sub> throws
>        /  
>      <sup>*T*</sup> ⁄ <sub>6</sub> sequences
>  
>          =  
>      1 <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>  throws /sequence.

**Notes**

The expected number of rolls seems suspiciously small but,
as seen among the example throws above,
it reflects the likelihood that
most evens-ending-with-**6** sequences will
be just 1 roll long, a lone **6**.
This does make sense after all by noting that
each sequence-ending **6** has
<sup>4</sup>⁄<sub>6</sub>  chance of
following a **1**, **3**, **5** or **6**(!) that
allows no prior rolls to count in that **6**’s sequence.

The condition “all throws gave even numbers”
is a potent red herring that suggests **6**s
have equal status to **2**s and **4**s.
 
Their status is not equal, however,
after retaining all **6**s originally rolled
but discarding the <sup>3</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub>  of **2**s/**4**s
that did not lead to **6**s.

This solution’s approach does have a loose end, literally, as
[commented by Artur Kirkoryan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54974/elchanan-mossel-s-dice-puzzle#comment169783_55035).
Any stretch of *T*  throws *could* end
with a streak of **2**s/**4**s that might extend
to become a qualifying sequence of any length if allowed to continue.
That comment and
[Deusovi’s reminder](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54974/elchanan-mossel-s-dice-puzzle#comment169993_55035)
to take density into account
lead to the realization that possible **2**s/**4**s loose ends
would need an infinite *expected* length to make a difference
because any bounded expectation would have a vanishing effect
as *T*  increases without limit.
This further leads to acknowledgment that
**the evens-ending-with-6 sequences in question
  are only *assumed*, not proven, to have a finite expected length.**
Presumption of their nonetheless having a bounded expectation
forces any **2**s/**4**s loose ends to also have a bounded expectation
and thus not undermine this solution’s approach.

This solution ensued from surprise at the
match between the 4 kinds of non-**2**s/**4**s throws and the
<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub>  fraction
of undiscarded throws exhibited by a
[Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Index.html)
routine’s simulating a million throws at a time.

```
 ( defun RollEm (many)
   ( let ( (i many) (sixes 0) (streakSum 0) (streak 0) )
     ( while  (>= (setq i (1- i)) 0)
              ( pcase  (1+ (random 6))
                       (   2  ( setq streak   (1+ streak)             ) )
                       (   4  ( setq streak   (1+ streak)             ) )
                       (   6  ( setq sixes    (1+ sixes)              )
                              ( setq streakSum (+ streakSum streak 1) )
                              ( setq streak     0                     ) )
                       ( else ( setq streak     0                     ) )
     )        )
     ( insert ( format "\n%d (%d%%) undiscarded throws / %d streaks  =  %.3f\n"
                       streakSum
                       ( / ( + (* 200 streakSum) many) (* 2 many) )
                       sixes
                       ( / (float streakSum) sixes )
 ) ) )        )

 (RollEm 1000000)     249372 (25%) undiscarded throws / 166527 streaks  =  1.497
        ""            250234 (25%) undiscarded throws / 166972 streaks  =  1.499
        ""            249503 (25%) undiscarded throws / 166256 streaks  =  1.501
        ""            250777 (25%) undiscarded throws / 166953 streaks  =  1.502
        ""            249947 (25%) undiscarded throws / 166791 streaks  =  1.499
```

Comment: Wow, what a brilliant solution!

Comment: This is very nice analysis and I upvoted the answer, but I am not convinced the argument is very rigorous. We still have to argue that the various halted 2-4 sequences are represented the same way in the long term, and justify taking T to infinity. I assume there is a theorem which states something like this, e.g. "if we have a sequence of experiments one after another, grouped by outcomes, then the statistical length of the experiment in group X, converges to the truth average, under certain conditions".
Once again, I like this argument, but I think I like your first solution more:)

Comment: True about not treating infinity rigorously here, @Artur Kirkoryan.
I wanted to disagree but remembered the simple example
of comparing the population counts of primes versus whole numbers.
Finite comparisons produce increasingly large disparities in favor of wholes
whereas an infinite comparison comes out perfectly equal.

Comment: "An infinite comparison comes out perfectly equal"? Only in terms of cardinality. In terms of natural density (which I'd argue is more natural (pun completely intended) in this case), the natural density of the primes is 0, which seems perfectly consistent with disparities increasing as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I might understand your comments even better now, @Artur K and $\raise-.2ex\unicode{x40}$Deusovi,
and have added a **Note** about them.

Comment: An alternative argument: the probability of landing on one of $\{1,3,5,6\}$ is $p = \frac 4 6= \frac 2 3$. Your answer gives the intuition for why we seek the the expected number of rolls up to and including the first appearance of $\{1,3,5,6\}$, which is $1/p = \frac 3 2$ - using the well-known formula for the expected number of independent trials up to and including the first "success", where $P(\text{success})=p$. (This is the same formula that gives the expected number of rolls up to and including the first six as $1 \div \frac 1 6 = 6$, the example given in the question text.)

Answer (score 15):

Let $X_n$ be the event that the dice takes $n$ rolls to get the first 6, given all the rolls are even. Let $A_n$ be the event that it takes $n$ rolls to get the first 6, and let $B$ be the event that all rolls up to the first 6 are even.

$P(X_n)=P(A_n|B)=\dfrac{P(B|A_n)P(A_n)}{P(B)}$ (using Bayes' theorem)

Now:

$P(A_n)=\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}$ (since the first $n-1$ rolls are not 6 and the last roll is)

$P(B)=\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{i=0}\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{i}$
$=\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{i=0}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{i}$
$=\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{4}$ (since at each stage there is a 1 in 3 chance that the roll is 2 or 4 and a 1 in 6 chance of getting a 6 at each roll)

$P(B|A_n)=\left(\dfrac{2}{5}\right)^{n-1}$ (since the last roll is even but for all the other rolls there are 2 even outcomes and 3 odd outcomes)

So $P(A_n|B)$
$=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot\left(\dfrac{2}{5}\right)^{n-1}\cdot\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}}{\dfrac{1}{4}}$
$=\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot\dfrac{2^{n-1}\cdot5^{n-1}}{5^{n-1}\cdot6^{n-1}}$
$=\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}$

Now, we wish to find

\begin{align}
\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}i\cdot P(X_i)
&=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}i\cdot\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{i-1} \\
&=2\cdot\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}i\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{i} \\
&=2\cdot\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{i}\cdot\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{j}\right) \\
&=2\cdot\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{i}\cdot\dfrac{3}{2} \\
&=3\cdot\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{i} \\
&=\dfrac{3}{2}
\end{align}

So it takes on average 1.5 rolls for the dice to get a 6, given that all the rolls are even.

---

Gamow wants me to keep my previous solution: if you want to see it, [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/54976/1) it is. It is wrong because the definition of $B_n$ is faulty - for example, a sequence such as `26143` isn't counted in $B_5$ when it should be, and a sequence such as `24(16)` is counted in $B_2$ when it shouldn't be, since we are given that all the rolls up to the first six are even, not that the rolls up to a certain point are even.

Comment: Could you explain how ∑[1;∞]i(1/3)^i = ∑[0;∞]((1/3)^i⋅∑[1;∞](1/3)^j) ? thx

Comment: @Sousben We are adding 1/3+2/9+3/27+4/81…=1/3+1/9+1/27+1/81…+1/9+1/27+1/81+1/243…+1/27+1/81+1/243+1/729…+1/81+1/243+1/729+1/2187……=1x(1/3+1/9+1/27+1/81…)+1/3x(1/3+1/9+1/27+1/81…)+1/9x(1/3+1/9+1/27+1/81…)+1/27x(1/3+1/9+1/27+1/81…)…

Comment: Can you explain P(B) a bit more? I'd have expected it to depend on N since you are considering the chances of all N rolls being even. ie it would just be 1/3*(2/3)^n-1.

Comment: @Chris the reason why it's not the chance of all n rolls being even is because that counts configurations such as `26`, `264`, `2642` etc as part of $P(B)$ multiple times where in reality they should only be counted once as `26`.

Comment: Great answer! I wish you would have kept the first version, where the result was "3 rolls on average". (That's also the answer I came up with, and with which most other people come up. It takes some time to accept that this is wrong.)

Answer (score 9):

I believe the answer is

> $\frac{3}{2}$

This is computational calculation, so it is not statistical answer.

> Here is [the simple code](http://rextester.com/DXBX40332)

It is for the people who try to find it probabilistically.

Here is **the probabilistic solution**:

First of all, we know that the probability of getting 6 on the first roll is $\frac{1}{6}$, then getting 6 after an even roll is  $\frac{2}{6}\frac{1}{6}$, and so on as the equation below:

> $P_n=\left (\frac{1}{6}  \right )\left (\frac{2}{6}  \right )^{n-1}$

so if we calculate all possible solutions and sum them we will get the probability set among all other possibilities (such as getting odd after getting some even):

> $\sum_{1}^{\infty }\left (\frac{1}{6}  \right )\left (\frac{2}{6}  \right )^{n-1}=0.25$

So if we multiply this by $4$ we will normalize the probability and find the actual expected value of getting $6$ given that all the rolls are even as below such as;

1. Getting $6$ in the first roll expected value:

> $E_1=4\left (\frac{1}{6}  \right )\left (\frac{2}{6}  \right )^{1-1}=\frac{2}{3}$

2. Getting $6$ in the second roll (requires not getting $6$ in the first roll)

> $E_2=\left [1-4\left (\frac{1}{6}  \right )\left (\frac{2}{6}  \right )^{1-1}  \right ]+4\left (\frac{1}{6}  \right )\left (\frac{2}{6}  \right )^{2-1}=\frac{5}{9}$

In general, we can generalize the formula as below,

> $E=\sum_{1}^{n}(1-A_{n-1})+B_n$

$A_{n}$ represents the sum of previous normalized probabilities and $B_{n}$ is the normalized probability of getting 6 at that roll.

firstly:

> $A_n=\sum_{1}^{n}(4\times\frac{1}{6}\frac{2}{6}^{n-1})=1-3^{-n}$

secondly,

> $B_n=4\times\frac{1}{6}\frac{2}{6}^{n-1})=2\times 3^{-n}$

so

> $E_{2,\inf}=\sum_{2}^{\inf}(1-1-3^{1-n})+2\times 3^{-n}=\frac{5}{6} $

lastly, we are going to add the first result since the general sum will work after 1:

> $ E=E_1+E_{2,\inf}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{5}{6}=\frac{3}{2}$

So if we sum all possible outcome expected values, we will get the actual expected value of getting $6$ given that all the rolls are even:

> $E =\sum_{1}^{\infty}E_n=\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Whether your code is correct or not is hard to tell without comments, but it's easy to see that the output is 1 greater than the value you've given here.

Comment: If all the rolls are even, the probability of getting 6 tends to 1, so I don't follow your argument.

Comment: @boboquack it is not actually ignoring getting odd rolls. just i normalize the probability. i will explain it more after i arrive home

Comment: In any case, the probability of getting 6 tends to 1, and after normalising should be 4, then...?

Answer (score 6):

Somewhat related to Oray's solution.

The answer is

> $\frac{3}{2}$

Why?

> The average chance to get a 6 can be modelled using an infinite sum:
>  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2}{3} ^ r$$
>  Where $\frac{1}{3}$ is the chance to get a 6, $\frac{2}{3}$ is the chance to not get a 6 and $r$ is the number of fails.
>  This is equivalent to a geometric series with $a_0 = \frac{1}{3}$ and $r=\frac{2}{3}$
>  $$\begin{align}S_\infty &= \frac{ar}{1-r}\\ &= \frac{\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2}{3}}{1-\frac{2}{3}}\\ &= \frac{\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2}{3}}{\frac{1}{3}}\\ &= \frac{2}{3}\end{align}$$
>  The average number of rolls needed is just $\frac{1}{S_\infty} = \frac{1}{\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Where do you get S∞=ar/(1−r) from? I read that lim N→∞ = a(1−r^(N+1))/(1−r) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn  in which case the result would be 1 throw which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @sousben wait never mind, this is not right - I need to divide by number of rolls too, I mean it's only logical the chance to get 6 is 100% in the long run

Comment: Thanks it all makes sense now, I was making the same mistake as you and couldn't understand my result...

Comment: This works out in this case, but I'm not sure that it works generally.  If we get rid of the evenness condition (i.e., if we wanted the number of throws before seeing a 6 when throwing a dice normally and including all throws), I believe this approach would give `6/5`?  And it would give `2` if we discarded all throws that weren't, say, either 1 or 6.  Seems like in the end it just inverts the probability to not get a 6 on one roll.

Answer (score 4):

Going by definition of what is the expected number we get

> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \cdot 1/3 \cdot (2/3)^{n-1} = 3 $$
>
>  where 1/3 part is the probability to get "6" after reaching the n'th roll and $ (2/3)^{n-1} $ - probability to reach that step.

Edit: well, it looks like the "reroll" [only the steps that produce odd number] and "reset" [the whole sequence] interpretations are not equal and the later is the intended meaning of the question. Under the later the probability to roll "6" on each step is in fact

> not equal to 1/3 as in the first case.
>  Let $p_1$ be the conditional probability to roll "6" (equal for all steps because after roll of "2" or "4" all outcomes are still conditionally as probable as before the roll, just with the chain of rolls being longer by one). Conditional probability to roll "2" or "4" would be of course $1-p_1$.
>  Let "A" be the event that the first roll is "6", "B" be the event that the sequence ended on "6" and did not contain any odd numbers.
>
>  $$ \begin{align} p_1 & = P(A|B) \\ & = P(A \& B)/P(B) \\ & = (1/6)/(P(B)) \end{align}$$
>  $$ P(B)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/6 \cdot (2/6)^{n-1}=1/4 $$
>  $$ p_1=(1/6)/(1/4)=2/3 $$ which is indeed rather counterintuitive.

The final answer in this approach:

> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \cdot p_1 \cdot (1-p_1)^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \cdot 2/3 \cdot (1/3)^{n-1}=3/2$$

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling to get my head around this so I decided to test it programatically to see if I had misunderstood the question. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $die_size = 6;
my $number_of_runs = 100000;
my $total_count = 0;

sub count_rolls {
    my $number_of_rolls = 0;
    my $number_rolled = 0;
    while ($number_rolled != $die_size) {
        $number_of_rolls++;
        $number_rolled = 1 + int rand($die_size);
        if ($number_rolled % 2 == 1) {
            return count_rolls();
        }
    }
    return $number_of_rolls;
}

for (1..$number_of_runs) {
    my $roll_count = count_rolls();
    $total_count += $roll_count;
}

my $mean_count = $total_count / $number_of_runs;
print "$mean_count\n";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHRagMhEHzfr9iGFi4cpL1C8yL3JwW55LxW8DSsSmhLvv2qNpzGdB9Ed3Zm1t2TIPW2LN4KtI7k0TGI9/NAWuoPywDmL3wcpeBWfgvscc9SRvv5IIibiZPXNuS7lxh/oDNuUPxovHYBCUmw/oDpzckoZfEHMEQllJBUX4EREWOGzp9SCWwq@KHPjW6vDjFqi7Zld9jq0GGLMrRNgx6bLJcZcrozfsJX7AO1NI1BwnnS5b@bQugC@bxW1p0yuABMhrDpdrtq5NtihrF4Hfc/djcLafuSkCyixiwGvWrcEJ7rbTM4UZzRpiC96w1bll8)

The result this gives is:

> 1.5

Hopefully this is helpful to anyone else who is a bit confused here.